# Read access violation "pThread-> was nullptr" in function AfxEndThread

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a main thread that creates a worker thread based on CWinThread (worker1) and then proceeds to do some other tasks. At some point, the main thread posts PostMessage(WM_QUIT, 0, 0) on the worker1 thread and it begins to shutdown. The main thread continues execution and begins to create a new worker thread (worker2). While that is going on, the worker1 executes AfxEndThread, passes a guard clause that checks for pThread!=NULL and when it calls pThread->Delete() it throws the null pointer read access violation. Here I am adding the function AfxEndThread for quick reference:

```
void AFXAPI AfxEndThread(UINT nExitCode, BOOL bDelete)
{
...
    // remove current CWinThread object from memory
    AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE* pState = AfxGetModuleThreadState();
    CWinThread* pThread = pState->m_pCurrentWinThread;
    if (pThread != NULL)
    {
        ASSERT_VALID(pThread);
        ASSERT(pThread != AfxGetApp());

        // cleanup OLE if required
        if (pThread->m_lpfnOleTermOrFreeLib != NULL)
            (*pThread->m_lpfnOleTermOrFreeLib)(TRUE, FALSE);

        if (bDelete)
            pThread->Delete();
        pState->m_pCurrentWinThread = NULL;
    }
...
}
```

Now, the reason I mention the second thread is that the handle (pParam) that is passed to the function...

```
UINT APIENTRY _AfxThreadEntry(void* pParam)
```

when worker2 is created, is exactly the same as that of the worker1 when it was created.

I am puzzled about this behavior, which could be the cause of the null pointer exception. Why are these two handles the same? Is it normal?

The way I create the thread is as follows:

```
AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CDerivedFromWinThread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0, CREATE_SUSPENDED))
```

Please help me if you have an idea of how to avoid this behavior. 
Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with the pointer returned by `AfxBeginThread`

Comment: There's a bug in the code we cannot see. [mcve] required.

Answer (score 0):

I previously answered but I deleted my answer because it made no sense to me.

I'm thinking it can be a double Delete. It's not enough to test that it's not `NULL`. It may have been deleted and nullified by someone else between the `NULL`-check and the `Delete()`. Perhaps the code that's deleting stuff should be inside a critical section? Better yet, use c++11 `std::mutex`'s thus starting to improve that code to be more c++11 like.